# Windows 2008 Share Perimssions and NTFS Write Attributes Permission

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, file-permissions

It appears that there has been a subtle change in the way that share and NTFS permissions interact in Windows 2008 R2. In our application, we need to set the Write Attributes permission on in order to write to custom properties in OLE/DB documents. Under Windows 2003, setting the share permission to `Modify` would not conflict with this NTFS setting, but under Windows 2008 R2, we have to set the share permission to `Full Control` or the write to the custom properties will fail.

Please note that if I had my way, this would be fine. I consider share permissions to be poorly designed and there are other better ways to treat network and local users differently, if there is some need for that. But some of our customers have um, rigid, security policies.

Comment: I am not aware of any documentation of what the share permission "modify" actually consists of.

Comment: I'm aware of some MS documentation for DFS that states minimum [very permissive] share permissions for that... it's in a 2k8 DFS context, not a 2k8 shares in general context, but would that be useful?

Comment: Share permissions are an artifact from the FAT days where there were no filesystem permissions. They're best done away with via `authenticated users - full control` and dealt with at the NTFS level.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you are talking about here. There are no Share permissions called `Modify` in Windows Server 2003 and Windows Server 2008 R2:

[image: Share Permissions]

The interaction between Share permissions and NTFS permissions can be complex. Share permissions take a much simpler view of the world. Your granularity for Share permissions is limited to `Full Control`, `Change` and `Read`. There is no concept of a Share owner and no "Share permissions inheritance". To further complicate things you can have the same folder shared more than once, with each Share having independent permissions. If you have "nested" shares, you'll get the Share permissions of whatever shared you have mapped.

NTFS permissions are *always* enforced, even if a the user or process is remote. Windows will take into account both the Share Permissions and NTFS Permissions and "calculate" their effective permissions.

The general process is like this:

- Gather all of the Share permissions and combine them together. A `Deny` will override any `Allowed`.
- Gather all of the NTFS permissions the user has to the file. Make sure you account for both explicit and inherited NTFS permissions. Just as with Share permissions, a `Deny` will override any `Allowed` permissions. Remember to consider that NTFS permissions that are not inherited or explicitly assigned are *implicitly* set to `Deny`.
- Combine the Share permissions and NTFS permissions. Where there is an overlap the more restrictive of the set is the effective permission.

You are probably seeing a more restrictive interpretation of `Modify` (or `Change`?) in Windows Server 2008 R2 which is then calculated against your less restrictive NTFS permissions. I like @Helge Klein could not find any documentation on what constitutes actual atomic permissions of the `Modify` Share "meta-permission".

As you have discovered, this process is complex and prone to errors. Make your life simple and use NTFS permissions exclusively for your access control. Set your Share permissions so they are wide open (`DOMAIN\Authenticated Users` - `Full Control`) and then set the NTFS permissions to provide you desired access control - something like the following is typical:

- `DOMAIN\Authenticated Users` - `Read`
- `DOMAIN\Accounting-Users` - `Modify`
- `DOMAIN\IT-Admins` - `Full Control`

The [Access Token](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374909%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) the user or process ends up contains the more restrictive ACLs and not just a union of then. This is the only sane way to do it otherwise you have to maintain and troubleshoot your ACLs in two separate spots with two separate set of tools. That way lies the path of madness.